# Limit the number of non decimal digits in an edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext in which I have to enter only digits below 10000. 9999.99 is a valid entry but 10000 is not. Is there any way to limit the number of digits in the mantessa part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769577/how-can-i-limit-the-edittext-box-input-to-two-characters-after-a-decimal-place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line `android:numeric="integer"` and take a TextWatcher  check total value< 10000

```
<EditText android:numeric="integer"... />

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          float final =Float.valueOf(s.toString());
          if(final<10000)
             //accept
          else
             //reject
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputFilter in your edittext:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html