# EditText Input type Issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

There is a name `EditText` in my screen. I want to accept only alphabets means from a-z,A-Z 
and should not accept numbers, special chars.

I'am using `inputtype="textPersonName"` for that but its notworking, it accepts means showing all numbers, chars etc..

For phone field `inputtype="phone"` is working it accepting means showing numbers in field` only.

Why like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to restrict the characters that are permitted in your EditText control. You should be able to easily adapt the answer from [How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android/4401227#4401227) to do what you require.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to subclass EditText and detect key events.
Reject any character other than a-zA-Z
This is the only way to limit the acceptable characters.

A person's name could contain a number so textPersonName is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PHONETIC