# Implementing numeric integer only on EditText with KeyListener

Tags: android

What do I need to fill in on the setKeyListener parameter so that it has the same behaviour like `android:numeric="integer"` on XML?

Snippet:

```
paymentAmount = new EditText(this);
paymentAmount.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
paymentAmount.setMinimumWidth(100);
paymentAmount.setKeyListener(???);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [EditText Input type Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370193/edittext-input-type-issue) which recommends using an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android/4401227#4401227) is an example taken from the previous question I linked.

Comment: thanks, what do I need to change so only integer value is allowed?

Comment: See the example link I posted, it tells you exactly