# Desire Z with 2.3.3: TextWatcher not working -> bug in stock keyboard?

Tags: android, htcsense, textwatcher

I think I just encountered a quite annoying bug in the 2.3.3 release for the Desire Z (European version). The TextWatcher does no longer work when using HTC's stock keyboard. It works on other devices such as the Nexus One, Samsung Galaxy S, various Emulator versions, and even on a Motorola Milestone. Furthermore, functionality returns as soon as I use a different keyboard.

Usage (in brief) looks like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
(...)

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
}
```

Does anyone experience the same (obnoxious) behavior? And does anyone have a workaround that does not involve installing a different keyboard?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue on the same hardware, on a software written specifically for this machine.

I was about to tackle the problem, but it disappeared by itself, as my user has switched to another keyboard.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android/4401227#4401227), suggesting the use of an InputFilter. This is what I wanted to try, i.e. in the filter function, do whatever is needed when the text changes and then return null from the filter function.

Comment: thanks. am just glad that I am not the only one who experiences this