# How show default keyboard number in Edittext?

Tags: android

I want to input EditText som characters:
 android:digits="1234567890-_@#."
If I don't set `inputType` keyboard input Text is default.

I want show number keyboard show default.
But:

If in EditText design ,i set:

```
 android:inputType="number"
```

or

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

EditText don't show key (@,_)
How show default keyboard number (allow input `digits="1234567890-_@#."`) in Edittext?

Comment: the inputtype `number` does not contain `_@#`

Comment: Try using an InputFilter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926896/android-want-to-restrict-some-charaters-to-the-edittext

Comment: Contain # , not contain @ ,_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" 
            android:inputType="number"
            android:digits="1234567890-_@#."/>
```

It works for me and allow me to insert this characters "1234567890-_@#." only.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: android:inputType="number" don't contain @ and _

Comment: It is showing on my device keyboard. I have HTC with 4.0 os. Which device you are having?

Comment: On my emulator 2.2 I can see all the keys on keyboard except _. But that I can show with the `ALT` key.

Comment: i run on emulator 2.3.1:if i set android:inputType="number" don't contain @ and _

Comment: let me check with other emulators too :)

Comment: I have device with 2.3.3 os also and it shows all the keys on keyboard which you are required. So, don't bother about emulators, this code with works well with android devices.

Comment: ok, thanks. I run on my device 4.0 is ok. but emulator 2.3.1 is not.

Comment: I think it depend with device.

Comment: Probably yes. Because all device have its separate keyboard behaviour. But what we did is enough to survey wide range of devices.