# Android - Prevent whitespace characters (with I18N) in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

Got int'l android app, but whitespace characters in several languages are being recorded for things like a username. I need to prevent whitespace (regex: \S), but I can't seem to get TextWatcher implementation to check for them. Do I check each character in the CharSequence that's given? Even then, I can't seem to prevent that char from being entered originally.

In other words, how do I **prevent** tabs, spaces, carriage returns from being registered as a char input to an edittext.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can find a nice answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You `trim()` when your setting or getting the string in editText.

Like this:

```
String s = " someString ".
mEditText.setText(s.trim());
```

This will remove all the redundant white spaces.
Ask if any doubts.