# Limit languages in Android/iOS for input text

Tags: android, user-input, database-server

Is there any way to limit the input text of edittext to english and hebrew only?
Since data is transferred to a server SQL DB, and I do not want to store other languages....
So is it a way to limit to specific language input?

Or maybe there is other way to handle these situation so server will not crash...

Yoav

Comment: server crashes if you use a different language? How does the server even know what language the text you send is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom InputFilter and set it as a filter for your EditText. There's more info about how to do this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android). Here's an adaptation of what's there:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!isEnglishOrHebrew(source.charAt(i))) { 
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }

    private boolean isEnglishOrHebrew(char c) {
        . . .
    }
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```