# TypeInput in Android

Tags: android, input, types

I have a problem in input type attribute, I need a person name to be written in the edit text but when I run the application, the keyboard doesn't changed dynamically and it allows the user to enter any characters in the name field. Here is the code:

```
<TextView  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="Name:"/>

     <EditText  
         android:id="@+id/edittext"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:inputType="textPersonName"    
     />
```

Comment: Your trying to restrain the characters entered into the box to just alphabetical characters?

Comment: yes, I just want the characers to be alphabetic .. any help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can only use the input type attribute to limit to numbers. The link below might help you with you question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401227/1157215

Comment: I just wanna solve it using the input type attribute. I don't wish to go through such codes. :s

Comment: It looks like its either a filter, or setting up a listener. EditText does not support the filter you need.