# how to disable or remove setting button from on screen keyboard

Tags: android

I use android in kiosk mode so I don't have return key when keyboard setting activity is top!

i want remove or disable keyboard setting button from on screen keyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We cann't disable action button on the android keyboard. You will have to settle with chcking for empty string in editor action listener.

Please follow this

[Disable one key on custom keyboard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858881/disable-one-key-on-custom-keyboard-in-android)