# How to cancel A Key from custom keyboard after 1 click..!

Tags: android, keyboard

hey How I can cancel number 1 that I pressed I want the user to use the number just once he can only reuse it if he backspace what he wrote or with enter button..!
is there a way that I can make the key number 1 to do unclickable or gray that the user cannot click on it??? plz look at the pic and you will understand or maybe editText dont allow to rewrite number 1 again ...!
if you want I can put my codes and thank you

[image]

Comment: Just add some buttons below your screen and block keyboard from opening! You can google it :)

Comment: i don't wont to block my keyboard :O

Comment: then use Edit watcher and check every char is present or not ...........

Comment: is it possible to block just the pressed key from the keyboard ?

Comment: even 3 years ago somthing similer no one knew :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858881/disable-one-key-on-custom-keyboard-in-android

Comment: anyone ...!? :(