# EditText.getText() not returning the value from setText()

Tags: android-edittext

Why isn't getText() returning the value I just provided to setText?

```
mEditText.setText("150");
String text = mEditText.getText().toString(); //result: "6"!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: There was an `InputFilter` (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401227/733092)) that was intercepting input to the EditText.