# Check blank space when clicking in a EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a customized `EditText` class, whats is happening is that there is a validation already for the field, checking it's length and doing trim.

But, the app is crashing because it is possible to click in the field and insert data after 1 space.

How can I validate when clicking, that user can not write his data? If he/she writes data with one space, the app crashes and I receive the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start position must be less than the actual text length
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code where the error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can trim but remember this wont restrict to enter white spaces by user, If you want to restrict white spaces then you need to add `filter` for your `edit text`. Adding `filter` let you restrict what ever character you want to avoid.

P.S - Check for adding filter on given link [How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

Comment: Arfin, thanks... I already have a mask for this.

How can I create this filter?

Comment: go through this given link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 1):

add "addTextChangedListener" to your EditText and then onTextChanged you can check for your validation. For example,

```
txtEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str = s.toString();
            if(str.length() > 0 && str.startsWith(" ")){
                Log.v("","Cannot begin with space");
                txtEdit.setText("");
            }else{
                Log.v("","Doesn't contain space, good to go!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Atul, the problem is that no text has changed. The app is crashing when user clicks and left space in the field.

Comment: @Leonardo, could you please paste some of your code, that will help understand the issue better?

Answer (score 0):

trim the string that you get from edit text.

```
   String str=edtext.getText().toString().trim();


if(str!=null && !str.equalsIgnoreCase("")))
{
//perform your operations. 
}
else
{
//give error message.
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say but I'm already doing this validation.
final int number = Integer.parseInt(formNumber.getTextField()
      .getText().toString().trim());

Answer (score 0):

Get the edit text first by this way:

```
EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
String txtEdit=txt.getEditableText().toString();
```

then check the text length validation by:

```
if(txtEdit.length() == 0)  {

               //your code for what you want to do.

}
```