# EditText bug: content duplicates after pressing a restricted character

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText with restricted characters. I allow digits only as

A strange thing appears on a Galaxy S4. It didn't appear a HTC Desire HD, HTC Desire X and a ZTE Blade.

1. I type `dddsss`
2. I type a swedish character like `å`.
3. It's not appearing as it is not an allowed character, so the content is still `dddsss`
4. I type a character, e.g. `u`
5. The content of the EditText becomes `dddsssdddsssu`
6. I type another character, e.g. `t` and the content becomes `dddsssdddsssudddsssut`

It sometimes happens when I press the backspace as well, so it must be a button press issue.

I added `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` but it didn't help.

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/comment_et"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:paddingLeft="5dp"
      android:paddingRight="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/idea_edittext"
      android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,!,@,#,$,%,^,(,),_,+,-,[,],{,},:,;,&apos;,|,\,.,/,ß,?,~,="
      android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
      android:textSize="16dp" />
```

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: No, it's a bug with many Samsung devices, including yours. It seems to affect some Latin extended characters like "ư", "ơ", "å", etc, so when you type these characters in an `EditText`, you'll get nothing returned.

Comment: You misunderstood. Those characters are not returned because they are restricted with the `digits` attribute. The problem is what I typed before is duplicated after typing these characters

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android?rq=1) (found under **Related** on the right of the post) might help.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? i have same. thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't remember how I solved this

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem and solved with changing EditText's inputtype to:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

I don't know if it's a proper solution but it's ok for me.

Comment: Tks for your answer, it saves me alot

Answer (score 0):

Personally, changing the EditText's inputtype to:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

did not work. But I noticed that the content duplication does not occur anymore when the back key is pressed. I know this is probably not a right way to solve the problem, but awaiting a real solution, and if it can help some people, I did a little trick on my EditText to solve the problem :

```
 private string formerText = null;
 private bool isEditLocked = false;

 editText.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!isEditLocked)
                {
                    var currentSelection = editText.SelectionStart;
                    isEditLocked = true;
                    if (formerText != null && editText.Text == formerText)
                    {
                        if (editText.Text.Length == 0)
                        {
                            editText.Text = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var lastChar = editText.Text[editText.Text.Length - 1];
                            editText.Text = editText.Text.Remove(editText.Text.Length - 1);
                            editText.Text += lastChar;
                        }
                    }
                    formerText = editText.Text;
                    editText.SetSelection(currentSelection);
                    isEditLocked = false;
                }
            };
```

As you can see, I just programmatically remove the last char of my EditText, then add it again, and then the duplication problem is gone.

Note that this is Xamarin.Android code, so this is written is C#, but you should be able to convert it into Java quite easily (editText.Text = ... becomes editText.setText(...) and so on).

Please, if someone find a REAL solution to this problem, post it there, because it still happens in semtember 2017