# How to disable to delete keys on Android Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

Looking to disable the `.`,`?`, `1`,`2` etc on the android keyboard.

I was thinking `if` the key is entered, run a method that converts it from `"."` to `""` for example.

Or just straight up disable them from being entered.

How do I go about this?

Comment: What's your use-case? There are several InputFilters which already exist (e.g. telephone numbers, which prevents letters). These **ignore** input from certain keys, they do not (cannot) disable the key on the keyboard itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the keys on the soft keyboard like that... the closest to that functionality would be specifying `inputType` for the `EditText` but obviously that only works with things like `number`, and you can't do that for a specific custom set of keys like the set you mentioned.

Instead look into `InputFilter`, as explained here:
[How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

Specifically the second answer (with modified if statements to fit your requirements):

```
new InputFilter() {
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
        SpannableStringBuilder sourceAsSpannableBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder)source;
        for (int i = end - 1; i >= start; i--) { 
            char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
             if (currChar=='.' || currChar=='?' || Character.isDigit(currChar) && !Character.isSpaceChar(currentChar)) {    
                 sourceAsSpannableBuilder.delete(i, i+1);
             }     
        }
        return source;
    } else {
        StringBuilder filteredStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
            char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
            if (currChar=='.' || currChar=='?' || Character.isDigit(currChar) && !Character.isSpaceChar(currentChar)) {    
                filteredStringBuilder.append(currentChar);
            }     
        }
        return filteredStringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
}
```