# Android multi line textedit height grows too much

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I want to have two multi line textedits, which both grow as more stuff get typed in.

This is what I have got so far:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    // Some other stuff

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_lists_repeat"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multi_line_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/multi_line_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multi_line_text_view_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/multi_line_edit_text_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are some problems though:

1. `EditText` grows and grows infinitely if you just press enter

   - would be nice if the `EditText` grows only until all space is taken of the view and no more further
2. When selecting words in `EditText` the [Action Bar at the top for copying / pasting / cutting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u1b7.png) is not always shown especially if you select something at the bottom of the `EditText` or if the `EditText` is big

How can I address those issues?

**EDIT**

I don't want to set a maximum of lines, since we have different screen sizes and therefore a hard coded number is not really a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
android:maxLines="5"
```

or

```
your_text_view.setMaxLines(5);
```

**EDIT:**

or you can hook up `addTextChangedListener()` to your edit text:

```
your_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(this);  
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Here you can take necessary action if the edit text grows beyond some height
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set a maximum lines, since we have different screen sizes and therefore a hard coded number is not really a solution.

Comment: you can hook up a `onTextChangeListener()` and not allow new-lines

Comment: Don't you mean `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher ...`

Comment: Even then it won't let me block the input. If I wanted to do that, I would have to use an `InputFilter`.

Comment: yes `InputFilter` will be great idea if you want to completely disallow new line chars and limit your line. found this [post for inputfilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401227/3326331)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61339/discussion-between-niklas-and-sagar-pilkhwal).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/multi_line_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>
```

Comment: I don't want to set a maximum lines, since we have different screen sizes and therefore a hard coded number is not really a solution.

Comment: it could be set dynamically then?