# text entered in an edittext vanishes on newer android versions when the text has a condition

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project where in certain edittexts i want it to contain only alphabets(both small and caps) and white spaces.So i set it dynamically in code as follows:

```
txtoccupation.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return src;
                        }
                        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }


                }
            });
```

The above code works fine in my older android 2.6 phone.That is , when i type in anything other than alphabets and white spaces it wont be shown on the edittext.But when i try  the above on a new kitkat device, the text disappears and is shown in the suggestions below.How do i fix this issue?

EDIT:
I used an input filter

```
filter = new InputFilter() { 
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                            if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))&&!Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                    return ""; 
                            }
                            if(Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))){
                                return " ";
                            }
                    } 
                    return null; 
            } 
    };
```

Comment: what character encodings are you using?

Comment: @SanjayManohar I dont understand what u r saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use input filters like this:

```
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                            return ""; 
                    } 
            } 
            return null; 
    } 
    }; 

    edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Taken from [How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to the edittext(in your xml), you want to restrict to have alphabets only

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

Comment: i have edited my answer..add space too with text..then it will take spaces also

Answer (score 0):

if (currentString.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchString ))
{
                            your code
}

android provides methods with strings like toLowerCase(),toUpperCase() etc