# Ensuring a user doesn't enter a space in an EditText

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext

I'm using some regex to validate an EditText and am trying to ensure that a user won't enter a space/whitespace. My current regex is: `"^[A-Za-z0-9][\\w.-]+$";`

Does anyone have any idea? I did a little research and discovered adding in \\s detects spaces but it didn't help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `string.contains()`seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: I'd like to keep the entire validation in this REGEX though, if possible.

Comment: It is much easier to disallow user to enter space, rather than allowing user enter all characters except _space_

Comment: You need to use `InputFilter` for your purpose.. This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your regex matching only when the string doesn't contain any spaces you can try:

```
^[^\s]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for `^[^\\s]*`

Comment: Where would this be added into the current regex I have?

Comment: You can use this instead of current regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[\S]*$
```

`\S` matches any **non-whitespace** character.