# android how to make edittext input can't be started with zero(0)

Tags: android

how to make edittext input can't be started with zero? example: 01000 or 0987654321 so on , or we input some value first , example 98124723475 then we add zero(0) in front 098124723475. i am making an app to calculate some prices this bugged me. Suppose the user found this, the edittext is able to input "0" that's bad.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3349121/102937

Comment: i don't think its related to this, that one talking about characters limitation. Are you implying to tell me to use intent filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement addTextChangedListener for editText and check the entered text start with zero or not, like:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
                String enteredString = s.toString();
                if (enteredString.startsWith("0")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                            "should not starts with zero(0)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (enteredString.length() > 0) {
                        editText.setText(enteredString.substring(1));
                    } else {
                        editText.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this through check that entry start woth 0 or not using this.

```
edittext.getText().toString().startsWith("0");
```

using this if condition is true than display Toast msg or execute what u want.

And you can also use TextWatcher with Edittext. using this u can check every time that user entered 0 or not.

Answer (score 2):

listen for the Key Stroke event for the EditText and check the keypressed to 0.
or

```
    *yourEditText.getText().toString().startsWith("0");*
```

This might work on button click

Answer (score 2):

Just do this dude..

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().startsWith("0"))
                editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().substring(1));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the some problem.
Fix with this

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        //...

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = s.toString();
            int len = s.toString().length();
            if (len > 1 && text.startsWith("0")) {
                s.replace(0,1,"");
            }
        }
    });
```