# Allow accent character in Edittext using digits Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using Edittext which is allowed to specific characters. Like a-z A-Z 0-9 and Special characters like )&'(".

For the above requirement I used **digits** in **Edittext** to restrict rest of the other special characters getting typed.

The digits not supported ' & " chars so I used html code &apos ; &amp ; &quot ; respectively.

Now the problem is I want to allow **accent** characters too. I found the html code for accent Á is &Aacute ; but **digits** is showing error like

" **The entity "Aacute" was referenced, but not declared.** ".

Kindly provide any solution for this or Is there any solution to allow accent character with a-z,A-Z,0-9  and 5 special character   )&'("   in Edittext?

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
               if ( !Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i)) || Character.toString(source.charAt(i)) .equals(")") || 
                 !Character.toString(source.charAt(i)) .equals("(")  ||
                !Character.toString(source.charAt(i)) .equals("\'")  ||
                !Character.toString(source.charAt(i)) .equals("&")  ||
                !Character.toString(source.charAt(i)) .equals("&")) { 
                            return ""; 
                    } 
            } 
            return null; 
    } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: I already aware of this, when I use this while typing and press space it automatically uses suggested words. Ex If you type "appl" and pressing space it automatically turn into "applied"

Comment: Set this in your layout's xml for your EditText:

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Or call setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS) in your Activity'

If you need to support API 4 and below, use android:inputType="textFilter"

Comment: Good suggestion on inputtype. finally it works with below java code with your suggestion.

Comment: The java code not used from yours instead I use another one any way I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

much easier:

```
    <EditText
        android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

Here in this digits: add your accent characters too

Just a word of caution, the characters mentioned in the android:digits will only be displayed, so just be careful not to miss some out :)