# EditText inputType property seems to be working incorrectly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

When I set the inputType attribute to number(android:inputType="number") and setting the digits attribute like this ***android:digits="0123456789"***. The input event is working correctly as expected. That is receiving the input as number only.[Refer the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n63Cw.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I set the inputType attribute to textPersonName (android:inputType="textPersonName") and setting the digits attribute like this ***android:digits="0123456789"***.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The input event is not working correctly as expected. That is,

- when I type 1, the EditText displays 1.
- when I continue typing b, the EditText displays 112.
- when I continue typing with 3, the EditText displays 112123.
- when I continue typing with 4, the EditText displays 1121231121231234.
  [Refer the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF4Z7.png)

What is the reason for that?

Comment: remove the digits attribute from both of the EditText

Comment: What are you looking for Person Name with NumberS?

Comment: what do you want actually ?

Comment: Sorry for not attaching the screen shots. I am curious about knowing the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input filter for specific character in edittext,You can allow only that character which you want to show.

Check my answer from this link:

[How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android/29025403#29025403)

Try this once it looks like device specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Digits with a text input type is an invalid combo.  digits says that a numeric type will be assumed.

As for the weird input-  my guess would be a misunderstanding between the keyboard and the edit text on what the status of text completion should be.  I saw similar errors when I wrote keyboards when the edit text was trying to override what I was typing-  it resulted in text completions being committed because it looked like the cursor moved.  The Android keyboard API is really in need of an overhaul.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

**What actually this attribute does ?**

What ever input type you specified as `android:inputType` It doesn't matters. It only matters what are the digits that this `EditText` will accept. If you set so, It specifies that this has a numeric input method and that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept which are (0-9) in your case. and numeric is implied to be true. The default is `false`.

**So if you want that not to happen you should remove this line.**