# Allow specific characters in EditText and block all other Characters Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to allow some specific characters in Edittext and block all other characters. I have searched the internet and didn't found a solution. All i found out was how to block specific characters but in my case i want to allow specific characters and block all other characters.
For example the characters that i want to allow in edittext are A-Z, 0-9 and a comma, dot and underscore(_) that's it. If someone can give me an example of how to do that or point me to the right link i will be very grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: This question already has an answer in input filter section.[See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

Comment: I hope your application is English-only and won’t have to deal with different localization. Restricting input to US-ASCII doesn’t always seem to be the greatest thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to allow only certain characters is to use a `TextChangedListener` with a `Pattern`

```
final Pattern pAlpha = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z,._]+");
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (pAlpha.matcher(yourEditText.getText()).matches()) {
        // you allowed it
    } else {
        // you don't allow it
    }

 }
});
```

Comment: While others were marking my post as negative. You provided me me with the best solution!
Thanks man!