# edit text mask Character and Number android studio

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make my edit text has formatted like : A001  (CharacterNumberNumberNumber) 
any idea? 
tried to find masking method but most of them for number only, 
if you have any reference please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

also see [How do I use InputFilter to limit characters in an EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

You could go with TextWatcher or InputFilter

Some of the issues that any of these solutions brings could be avoided by using a custom keyboard for this EditText