# InputFilter removes whole text

Tags: android, regex, input-filtering

I entered 3 alphabet character android clears input. I expected to remove last , 3rd character, not full text

[image]

update , removed regex regarding comment below and still same result

```
private final Integer mAlphabetCount = 2;

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

    String text = createResultString(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);

    if (text.length() <= mAlphabetCount) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetter((source.charAt(i)))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    char[] digit = text.substring(2).toCharArray();
    for (char c : digit) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    return source;
}

private String createResultString(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    String sourceString = source.toString();
    String destString = dest.toString();
    return destString.substring(0, dstart) + sourceString.substring(start, end) + destString.substring(dend);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

First of all you need to decide what you want to happen in case of wrong user input. For example, the user already entered "AB" and now tries to enter "C". Do you want to discard the "C"? Do you want the input field to become "BC"? Let's say you want to discard the "C".

Check if `source` is an instance of `Spanned`. If so, then you cannot just send back an empty String if the input is invalid, or it will erase the textbox (this is happening to you now). You need to extract the correct part from the `source` and send it back. Since we decided to just discard all letters after the first 2 you can try to match `source` against `^([a-zA-Z]{0,2})(?:[^\d]*)(\d{0,7})`. Then send back the result composed of matching group 1 + group 2, i.e. first 2 letters + first 7 digits.

If `source` is not an instance of `Spanned` you can check if dest + source matches `^[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{0,7}$`. If yes, send back `null`, otherwise discard the input - send back an empty string.

Comment: thanks for answer, but the problem is that after first check [A-Za-z]{0,2}  < it works good, if the 3rd character is incorrect android clears whole textview :(

Comment: Aha, so you have a problem with a dictionary completion. Check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android

Comment: can you add tested example as answer ? For example, the user already entered "AB" and now tries to enter "C". Do you want to discard the "C"? - yes "C" should be dismissed. I tested several variants and doesn't work correctly .

Answer (score 0):

Here is all I need, actually there are no need to use regex, but it will work the same way. [answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12656159/2498416)

```
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
        SpannableStringBuilder sourceAsSpannableBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder) source;
        for (int i = end - 1; i >= start; i--) {
            char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
            if (i < mAlphabetCount) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
                    sourceAsSpannableBuilder.delete(i, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                if (!Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
                    sourceAsSpannableBuilder.delete(i, i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return source;
    } else {
        StringBuilder filteredStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
            if (dest.length() < mAlphabetCount) {
                if (Character.isLetter(currentChar)) {
                    filteredStringBuilder.append(currentChar);
                }
            } else {
                if (Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
                    filteredStringBuilder.append(currentChar);
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredStringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```