# InputFilter for restricting EditText input to HEX (android:digits not working)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

How to write InputFilter to restrict EditText input to HEX numbers? I need to restrict all characters except **0123456789abcdefABCDEF**

**android:digits**  doesn`t work anymore after I increased target api from 29 to 30:

```
android:digits="0123456789abcdefABCDEF"
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hex_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_hex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:digits="0123456789abcdefABCDEF"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Attempt**

I can ignore unwanted characters using:

```
if (editText_hex.getText().toString().matches("[0-9a-fA-F]{6}")){
...
}
```

But I want to restrict input (not ignore)

Comment: You could try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4401227/2930834

Comment: @Nakul, there are comments below this solution that it doesn't work in newer Androids (like 4.0+)

Comment: Refer to other solutions for that same question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    editText_hex.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(Pattern.compile("[^0-9A-Fa-f]").matcher(s).find()) {
                String s2 = s.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9A-Fa-f]", "");
                editText_hex.setText(s2);
                editText_hex.setSelection(s2.length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complicated way to do it, but not sure how effective it is.

You can use a `TextWatcher` to see what new letters are being typed. If the letter is something you don't want, you just set the text of the `EditText` to the new value but without the last character.

I've tried that for Enter (new line).