# EditText allow only two spaces and not allowing more than two spaces

Tags: android, android-edittext, space

In my application, I have edit text field. And this edit text filed should allow only two spaces for Example **Mike Graham John**. And not allowing more than two spaces like  the below word

**Mike Graham John Abraham**.
I have tried with InputFilter, but I am unable to get it.

Can any one please help me on this
Thanks!

Comment: What does your non-functioning `InputFilter.filter()` code look at the moment? Would it be possible to keep track of the number of spaces? Related discussion: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349121/how-do-i-use-inputfilter-to-limit-characters-in-an-edittext-in-android)

Comment: A [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) could be an alternative way to do this. (With its own caveats like infinite loops.)