# Validation on TextEdit boxes on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, validation

I wounder if there is some different way of validating EditText on android controlls.. 
Or should I use the regular java way of doing this?

Comment: If you call the `validate()` method, it reads your mind and knows if what the user input is what you consider valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of validation are we taking about?

Numbers:

```
android:numeric="decimal"
```

Length:

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

You can also provide "hints" of what the valid data should be:

```
android:hint="@string/numberHint"
```

[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your requirements are, you can look at the [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) attribute. This can be quite a bit easier in some cases. For example, specifying `android:inputType=number` will simply disallow non-numeric symbols from being entered into the EditText box.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want some fancy validation use the java.util.regex class

[link text](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

(Matcher and Pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Validation is somewhat tedious. Maybe I can help you in a more generic manner. I have written a basic framework to [validate fields in Android](http://dekwant.eu/?p=138).

It is totally free, and you can do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    nPassword.setError("Password is required");
                    return;
                }

if(password.length() < 6){
                    nPassword.setError("Password must be greater than 6 characters");
                    return;
                }
```

''''''''''

"These are two sample validation, one checks if EditText is empty or not. Second one checks if length of the string in edit text is greater than 6 or not."