# Handling Data entry mistakes in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a built-in mechanism in android for handling data entry mistakes inside a data entry form in Android, similar to the one that exists in .Net Framework?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input

Comment: Maybe you are right, I am checking it out, Thanks :)