# How to perform validation in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `EditBox` where I have to check if the number entered by the user is correct or not. For doing so I want to call such an event that allows the user to type a number in the `EditBox` whenever the number is correct, otherwise, if the number is not correct it doesn't allow the user to type in the `EditBox`. How That can be done? Any example will be helpful for me.

Comment: Which kind of NUMBERS you want to allow and which are not. Give example or pattern for validation.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2763022/1021695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `onTextChangedListener()` and validate inside its beforeTextChangedMethod() .. something like this..

```
 ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_testo)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.numcaratteri)).setText(String.format(getString(R.string.caratteri), s.length()));

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // Validate here

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

Comment: Actually During Typing in the edit box only i want to validate the number and i don't allow the user to type wrong date. Means the user can only type correct number. I don't allow user to type the wrong number.

Comment: @Anshuman .. then don't clear text inside the method if its invalid else set it...

Comment: Can u show me with an example..please i am stuck in it for an hour

Answer (score 2):

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            s.replace(0, s.length(), s.toString().replaceAll("[0-9]", ""));
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
            int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});
```

Comment: Really brilliant! Right on the money :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29).

You can Just Go [HERE](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/11/23/android-validation-with-edittext/). Example is also given here, you can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 ways
1. textwatcher
2. Inputfilter
i am attaching the code which includes both

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {   
EditText editTxt;  
private TextView regresult;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    editTxt =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editID);
    regresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtID);
    String urName=editTxt.getText().toString();

    editTxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DecimalDigitsInputFilter()});      
    editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {    
        }           
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }           
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              if (editTxt.getText().toString().matches("(^([0-9]{0,3})?)(\\.[0-9]{0,1})?$"))
                {
                    regresult.setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    regresult.setText("invalid number");
                }
        }
    });
}}  


class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter
{   
Pattern mPattern;

public DecimalDigitsInputFilter()
{
    mPattern = Pattern.compile("(^([0-9]{0,2})?)(\\.[0-9]{0,1})?$"); //here u can give your required pattern
}
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(dest);
        if(!matcher.matches())
        {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
}}
```