# android EditText value

Tags: android, android-widget

I have the weirdest problem...

all I am trying to do is to get the value from a EditText and do some validation.

The value in the edittext must be between 1 and 10. However, even if I enter any number between 1 or 10 , it still validates false. I even tested the edittext input to make sure it is correct , and it is, but the if still fails . Any ideas ?

here is the code:

```
ed = (EditText) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.ed_quantity);                                                  
Button bq = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.alert_a);
dialog2.setCancelable(false);
dialog2.show();
bq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String test = ed.getText().toString();
        Toast toast23452234 = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Quantity: "+test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast23452234.show();
        if(test=="1"||test=="2"||test=="3"||test=="4"||test=="5"||test=="6"||test=="7"||test=="8"||test=="9"||test=="10")
        {
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString());
            dialog2.dismiss();
            ed.setText("1");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast2345223 = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Quantity must be between 1 and 10" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast2345223.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input

Comment: try this `test.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("1")` in your if-condition

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 test.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("1")
```

in your if-condition

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` method to compare strings..

```
if(test.equals("1")||test.equals("2")||test.equals("3")||test.equals("4")||test.equals("5")||test.equals("6")||test.equals("7")||test.equals("8")||test.equals("9")||test.equals("10"))
```

or use int to compare

```
int test = Integer.valueOf(ed.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is not a native type so you can't do `test=="1"`. This compares the object references and obviously the two objects have different references.

Call `equals(Object object)` method on string object. Like,

```
test.isEquals("1")
```

Better parse the input string to integer as

```
int testInteger = Integer.parseInt(test);
```

and compare as

```
if(testInteger==1 || testInteger ==2)
```

This saves many method calls to string object.

Answer (score 0):

use .equals("") in case of String.

```
if(test.equals("1")||test.equals("2")||test.equals("3")||test.equals("4")||test.equals("5")||test.equals("6")||test.equals("7")||test.equals("8")||test.equals("9")||test.equals("10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

use .equals on string operation instead of ==

```
  if(test.equals("1")||... and so on)
```

or else convert string into "int".

Answer (score 0):

Use `test.equals("1")` || .....

You can also do this

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(test);
if(t == 1 || t == 2 || ...)
```