# How can I limit the values of MultiAutoCompleteTextView to be only the items from my adapter?

Tags: android, multiautocompletetextview

This is the code I'm using:

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView selectedCities = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.citiesSelected);

String[] cities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cities);
        selectedCities.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectedCities.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

but when i want to add items it is possible to add any string not from my list...

I dont want to use Alert Dialog with MultiChoiceItems since I have more than 200 items on my list.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if you still have this problem, you can do this in at least two ways:

1. You can add an onFocusChangeListener and then perform your
       validation inside of that.

   You can have your activity implement `TextWatcher` and
       then override:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // validation code goes here
}
```

About the last one, take a look at this question: [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input).