# Set validation to android EditText with c#, xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to add validation to my EditText. I have a mail sending form and if some field is empty I want to highlight EditText borders and notify user that the field is required.

Comment: SO is a Question and Answer forum.  To get a good Answer, you should start by asking a good Question.  What you've posted isn't actually a question, just a "I want".  Please refer to "How to Ask" in the Help for suggestions on how to write a good Question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input

Comment: Just check in your sendbutton press if the edittext has value or not. If not chanche the border color and focus the field.