# How to refresh the RecyclerView when taking input from edit text using Databinding

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-databinding

```
First time data loaded correct in recyclerview using databinding ,Need to update the recylerview when user type anything in editText , onTextchange getting new list that need to show in recylerview but its showing old list only.
How to implement this using Databing.
```

Code -:
    In Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FoodsAdapter.ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        binding=holder.getBinding();
        binding.setAdapter(this);
        binding.setActivity(mActivity);
        binding.setVariable(BR.food,foodList.get(position));
     /*   binding.setFood(foodList.get(position));*/
        binding.setPosition(position);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

Set Adapter in RecylerView

```
 binding.rvFood.setAdapter(null);                                  
 binding.rvFood.setAdapter(new FoodsAdapter(activity,foodList));
```

Getting old list with new one when i enter anything in edit text  but when coming from background to foreground correct data shows .

Answer (score 0):

Use adapter to notify the change of data. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I am setting new adapter every time when list change ,but still its showing same list. Also done binding.executePendingBindings();

Comment: Buddy, you should post your code in the question, not in the comment...@Dummy

Comment: sorry i was not aware of this.

Comment: Please also show me how you implement EditTextView input function

Comment: You also need to add some listener for you edittext, 
check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input
If you have more questions, let me know

Comment: Please select the tick if this answer is helpful to you :D

Comment: on edittext calling text watcher  android:onTextChanged="@{(s, start, before, count)->foodFragment.onFoodTextChanged(s)}" .In this function api call is there that fetch new list after that setting  adapter ...

Comment: yeah, you should go a head and try it, if it doesn't work please paste your code in the question @Dummy