# Forcing User to Input Something in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have several EditTexts in my Activty and I want my users to give inputs correctly before submitting the form. How can I do It? 
I have also spinners and RadioGroup Button.

Comment: What do you mean by "give input correctly" ? Do you want to check if the editText is empty ?

Comment: it cannot be empty it should have some specific  length

Comment: Misbah Ahmad, check my answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add **Validation** on submit button click:

```
private boolean validateFields() {
    int yourDesiredLength = 5;
    if (yourEditText1.getText().length() < yourDesiredLength) {
        yourEditText1.setError("Your Input is Invalid");           
        return false;
    }else if (yourEditText2.getText().length() < yourDesiredLength) {
        yourEditText1.setError("Your Input is Invalid");           
       return false;
    } 
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

On Submit button Click:

```
btnSubmit.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(validateFields()){
                // Then Submit 
            }
        }
});
```

Output will be like this. Photo [Credit](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-show-error-in-edittext/).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apply validation for editText and all your other components in **button.setOnClickListner**

if all the validation satisfy then do further process.

**like for edittext validation**

```
 Send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
if(edit.getText.equals(""))
{
  edit.setError("Please provide user name")
}
else
{
  //do your further activity
}
      }
                });
```

Comment: I tried this, but I have more than one EditText I want to detect the Error before Submit Button is pressed.

Comment: please share your code screen .so exactly i can know what is your problem @Misbah Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

Try this: code

> I want to detect the Error before Submit Button is pressed

use `setOnFocusChangeListener()` on the Editext

```
 editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

 editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     String value = editText1.getText().toString();
        if(value.length() == 0) {  
            //editext is empty
            if(! hasFocus){
                editText1.requestFocus();
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter value correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I get your point, you can use **TextInputLayout** instead of **EditText**

**define your `xml` layout:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

then you can use helper method inside your button click listener to validate the input data of all your editText

```
 public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;
        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 6) {
            _passwordText.setError("Password is too short !");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            _passwordText.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

don't forget to add the design support library dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
```

see this example: 
[Creating a Login Screen Using TextInputLayout](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168)

it will be something like that 
if the user enter invalid data it will show this warning in red lines 
[image]