# EditText unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText which simply should disallow typing specific letters. I have made a variable string with the accepted digits as follows: `<string name="accepted_digits">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&amp;-,\'</string>`

My EditText looks like this:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test_editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:digits="@string/accepted_digits"
        />
```

Now when I type an accepted digit followed by any digit **not** in the `accepted_digits` string it produces a weird behaviour i.e

`1st input = M` | Displayed: `M`

`2nd input = æ` | Displayed: `MM`

`3rd input = l` | Displayed: `MMMlMl`

`4th input = k` | Displayed: `MMMlMlMlk`

I did not intend this behaviour - I intended that an unaccepted digit would simply be skipped so my displayed input would be: `Mlk`.

I have tried simply changing the inputType to `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword` but I would like autosuggestion to be allowed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you put the strings directly in the EditText the same error happens?

Comment: android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&amp;-,\'"

Comment: yes, same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `characters` with `digits`. A digit is a character which has a numerical value while a character can be anything. In order to fix this you can not use `android:digits` but you can use `TextWatcher`. See [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)

Comment: I will try this asap.

Comment: It seems i can catch it this way. Not what i had hoped :( 
Thank you for you help :)