# How to validate text with lot of empty spaces?

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Description:**

I am creating an app in which you can change your profile´s name. The problem is that users can write their names with a lot of empty spaces and I don´t know how to avoid this problem.

**Example:**

*(I am going to represent empty spaces with underscore "_")*

**Edit your name:** T_____omas_Men________n____i_ti **//// *(31 chars)***

If someone writes that on an edit text, empty spaces are going to be saved and then we will see that large name into user's profile.

**What do I want?**

I need a code able to check when the edit text has more than one (**> 1**) empty spaces in a row in order to delete them. The code should be able to detect that *"name"* must have one empty space after *"last name"*

Comment: What did you tried? Have you considered using a regex to check if there are consecutive space in the string?

Comment: I was thinking for some minutes how to solve this problem but i think i am not able to solve this problem. I haven´t used regex yet. I will investigate it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to replace those multiple space between chars or restrict user by validation for including more than 2 spaces?

Comment: I want to restrict user of using more than 1 space in a row.

Comment: What language do you prefer for your answer? Also you shouldn't use the `android-studio` tag if the question or possible answers is not about android studio (the IDE)

Comment: I am using java

Comment: Check if number of " " in a row is > 1. If yes, remove them all. Leave only single occurances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TextWatcher as described here: [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)

Then in onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) method you can validate user input, here is example :

```
if (s.contains("  ")) {
    // ask user to edit input
    // or change text programatically
    String after = before.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    // set new text
}
```

Comment: Woww. This is a really simple and useful method that i didn´t know until now. Thanks you so much for helping. And thanks to all the others who tried to help too.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict EditText by using TextWatcher in tricky way.

Working flow for below code

- Create and added TextWatcher to EditText. Did the logic inside onTextChanged function

**Logic 1 :** To avoid empty space as a first character

**Logic 2 :** Restrict EditText to allow only one space after a character

**Logic 3 :** Restrict EditText to allow only one space for entire string

**Logic 4 :** Remove Text Change Lister before setting value in editText

**Logic 5 :** Set proper value in editText

**Logic 6 :** Again add Text Change Lister for editText

Try the below code.

```
package com.example.application;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String preValue = editText.getText().toString();

            /*
             *  To avoid empty space as a first character
             * */

            if (preValue.length() > 0 && preValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
                editText.setText(preValue.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }

            /*
             *  Restrict EditText to allow only one space after a character
             * */

            if (preValue.endsWith("  ")) {
                editText.setText(preValue.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }

            /*
             *  Restrict EditText to allow only one space for entire string
             * */

            if (preValue.trim().contains(" ") && preValue.endsWith(" ")) {

                /*
                 *  Remove Text Change Lister before setting value in editText
                 * */
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

                /*
                 *  Set proper value in editText
                 * */

                editText.setText(preValue.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());

                /*
                 *  Again add Text Change Lister for editText
                 * */
                editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }

            if (preValue.contains("---") && preValue.endsWith(" ")) {

                String[] words = preValue.split(" ");

                if (words.length >= 2) {
                    editText.setText(preValue.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
                    return;
                }

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                for (String word : words) {
                    stringBuilder.append(word).append(" ");
                }

                /*
                 *  Remove Text Change Lister before setting value in editText
                 * */
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

                /*
                 *  Set proper value in editText
                 * */

                editText.setText(stringBuilder);
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());

                /*
                 *  Again add Text Change Lister for editText
                 * */
                editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering a different kind of solution that focuses on working with bare Strings instead of the EditText. Bear in mind that this answer works in combination with the other answers here.

```
private static String filterMultipleSpaces(String s) {
    char[] result = new char[s.length()];
    int iC = 0;

    for (int iS = 0; iS < s.length(); ++iS) {
        char currentChar = s.charAt(iS);
        if (currentChar != ' ' || (iC > 0 && result[iC - 1] != ' ')) {
            result[iC] = currentChar;
            ++iC;
        }
    }

    return new String(result);
}
```

The above static function takes a String and removes multiple spaces. Ideally you would use this when the text changes ([see @Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60454534/1099775)) or when submitting the EditText's value if you wish